# Create a view with a variable number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

`select * from mytable` gives me a result set like:

```
evaluation | item | criteria | points
         1 | 1    | 1        | 111
         1 | 1    | 2        | 112
         1 | 2    | 1        | 121
         1 | 2    | 2        | 122
         2 | 1    | 3        | 213
         2 | 2    | 3        | 223
         2 | 3    | 3        | 233
```

and I want to end up with a view that puts all criteria used in an evaluation in the same row, for example:

`select * from myview where evaluation = 1` would get me

```
evaluation | item | points_1 | points_2
         1 | 1    | 111      | 112
         1 | 2    | 111      | 112
```

and the result set for `select * from myview where evaluation = 2` would be:

```
evaluation | item | points_3
         2 | 1    | 213    
         2 | 2    | 223     
         2 | 3    | 233
```

is that possible at all?

Comment: This is not possible.  A view has a fixed set of columns when it is defined.

Comment: More specifically, a view is defined by a single select query. *Any* specific query always has a fixed "shape" - the number of columns within it, the *types* of those columns and their names. The only way to get variable result sets is to construct new queries at runtime - but that needs more than a single select query.

Comment: ok, that's what I thought. I guess I'll have to fix the result set with some coding then ^^

Comment: You could do a stored procedure that returns variable number of columns using dynamic SQL

Comment: it will be application code. Stored procedures are not permitted on this project (Although I don't care. It's pretty much the same effort...)

Comment: Why can't you just have extra columns that have `NULL` values?

Comment: that would be a useful alternative, but since I have no way of knowing how many criteria will be added to the table, the view would still have a variable number of rows, so it is not possible either, right?